# Strip parameters from URL in session[:previous_url] in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to use override Devise's #after_sign_in_path_for in order to redirect to either the user's last URL page or the root path:

```
  # Redirects on successful sign in
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    puts session[:previous_url]
    if session[:previous_url] != email_confirmation_url
      session[:previous_url] || root_path
    else
      root_path
    end
  end
```

I do not want it to redirect to the previous page if the previous_url is the same as the email_confirmation_url. However, my issue is that I want it that rule to hold even if there are parameters added to the end of the session[:previous_url]. The issue that I'm running into is that

```
email_confirmation_url == /users/confirmation
session[:previous_url] == /users/confirmation?confirmation_token=HGESMzRz2sz1UbsvudSS
```

Or some other token value. I want to strip the confirmation token or any other parameters out of the URL and then do the comparison. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming all the URL parameters will be after `?` in the URL, you can just do this:

```
if session[:previous_url].split('?').first != email_confirmation_url
  session[:previous_url] || root_path
else
  root_path
end
```

You can alternatively check if `session[:previous_url]` starts with `email_confirmation_url` using [start_with?](http://apidock.com/ruby/String/start_with%3F):

```
if !session[:previous_url].start_with? email_confirmation_url
  session[:previous_url] || root_path
else
  root_path
end
```

Answer (score -1):

Try  using

```
request.path
```

or

```
request.base_url + request.path
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11544323)

Comment: Dude do you read the question, he is only asking how to not include the parameters in the url

Comment: @SpiderMan, why don't you just post your opinion or comment rather than criticizing others answer?

Comment: @Lymuel Relax, no harm is done :-) Stack Overflow gets *thousands* of answers a day, and unfortunately many of them are non-answers such as questions posted as answers, "thank you answers", or requests for clarifications. That is why there are [http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/ review queues] so that members can vet some of the posts to remove the fluff. This is why it says "From Review" at the end of SpiderMan's comment. Sometimes mistakes get made, but since multiple people review an answer it's usually fine if one person makes an oopsie :-)

Comment: @Carpetsmoker, I think my answer do answers the question above, becuase the question was only asking how to get the url without the paramteres, am I right?

Comment: @Lymuel I don't check if it's *correct*, but it's an attempt to answer the question and that's good enough ;-) Answers should not be removed for being incorrect (that's what downvotes are for) only for being non-answers. I just wanted to explain why SpiderMan's comment was there and that it's nothing to get excited over :-)

Comment: I am just telling to @SpiderMan because he is saying that it does not provide answer to the question.

Comment: @Lymuel There is no need for SpiderMan to provide an answer. Anyone is free to point out mistakes in other people's answers. You can only learn from that :-)

Comment: But what is my mistake, I think he is the one having mistakenly telling my answer does not support the question